# Want to check analyticity of a series on a open disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, analyticity

How do we check the analyticity of a any power series? For example:

How will we show that $$f(z):= \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}= z^1+z^2+z^6+z^{24}......+z^{n!}......$$ is anaytic on disk {$z : |z|<1$}

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficients $a_n$ of your power series are $0$ or $1$, and $a_n=1$ for infinitely many $n$, so $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=1$. Thus, your power series converges on the open unit disk by [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), and by standard results it is analytic on such disk.

Comment: Thank you Chibchas. Let me read this theorem first.

Comment: Hi @Chibchas, What is that result that says convergent series on the open unit disk are analytic on such disk. Sorry if you find my question silly. Actually I don't have any previous knowledge about it and now I am learning it on my own.

Comment: @SaraTancredi See [here](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/derivatives-of-power-series/)